# populate dropdown list from database when editing form MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am pretty new to PHP and am having a question about dropdown lists. I am trying to get the list to pull from the database and populate the value when a user edits a form but it is not currently working. There are a few examples of this exact same thing on here but I can't quite get it working, it is likely a syntax error on my end...

Here is my code:

```
echo '<p><label>Is this project targeted toward?</label><select name="proj_targ_tow"><option value="Select...">Select...</option><option value="National Site">National Site</option><option="Local Site">Local Site</option><option value="Regional Site">Regional Site</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select></p>';
```

And here is the logic to populate the value from the database, the row I am trying to pull from is 'proj_targ_tow'...

```
    $typesArray = array ( 'Select..', 'National Site', 'Local Site', 'Regional Site', 'Other' );
$selectedType = '';
echo 'as;ldfjas;lfmawoiealknfsliu2047a   ' . $row['proj_targ_tow'] . '<br />';
foreach($typesArray as $value){
    if($value == $row['proj_targ_tow']) {
        $selectedType = 'selected="selected"';
} 
echo '<option value="' . $value . '" ' . $selectedType . '>' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

Can any of you coding gods out there help me out?

Comment: aint no gods around mate

Comment: What is the value of $row['proj_targ_tow']?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you intended it, but make sure you do:

$selectedType = '' inside the foreach loop (at the start).

Comment: @TusharDhoot - when I echo it out it returns the value from the database (National Site)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the $value in your echo statement is out of scope... what happens when you do this?

```
$typesArray = array ( 'Select..', 'National Site', 'Local Site', 'Regional Site', 'Other' );

foreach($typesArray as $value){
    $selectedType = '';

    if($value == $row['proj_targ_tow'])
        $selectedType = 'selected="selected"';

    echo '<option value="' . $value . '" ' . $selectedType . '>' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: this is pretty much it, except for I needed an else to populate all the other values that are NOT selected. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I'm happy to have been of assistance.